# Configuration issue with "return 301" on nginx and aws

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, return, ubuntu-16.04, http-status-code-301

I have had a nginx server running on aws with an ubuntu 16.04 OS. My current sites SSL "return 301 https://$host$request_uri" works flawlessly but is not working on the new site.

I have tried configuring the default, and sites-enabled/website1.ca.conf and sites-enabled/website1.ca.conf

```
server {
server_name site2.ca www.site2.ca;
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
#return 301 https://site2.ca$request_uri;
root /var/www/vhosts/site2.ca/;
index index.html index.htm index.php;
```

This page isn’t working site2.ca redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Please provide all content of your nginx configuration ?**(https config)**
And check if application serve an **http** url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours and hours of jerking around I analyzed the SSL cert and realized that Cloudflare's default settings use their SSL rather than the sites.

Resolution was setting Crypto to Full SSL.